# Js not works after redirect

Tags: javascript

I'm using apppresser to build a WordPress APP and I would like to use a simple JS file to hide menu icon, in one page only.

When a user logs in, he is redirected to this page. JS I have written works, but when a user is redirected to this page after login, JS does not seem to be working.

It seems that after the redirect it loses the page reference.

Useful docs: https://docs.apppresser.com/article/392-custom-javascript

I have created a custom html page like this, and assigned a custom ID to div:

```
<img src="https://pathimage.com" onload="disableMenuToggle()" onbeforeunload="enableMenuToggle()" style="height:0px;width:0px; position:absolute;" />
<div id="pianoscaduto">
<button ion-button (click)="openPage('login-modale')">
<ion-icon name="ios-arrow-dropright" item-left></ion-icon>
  FAI IL LOGOUT
</button>
</div>
```

My JS is:

```
function disableMenuToggle(){
 var menutoggle = document.getElementsByClassName( 'bar-button-menutoggle' );
if ( menutoggle.length > 0 ) {
        menutoggle[0].disabled = true;
   }
  }

function enableMenuToggle(){
 var menutoggle = document.getElementsByClassName( 'bar-button-menutoggle' );
if ( menutoggle.length > 0 ) {
        menutoggle[0].disabled = false;
   }
  }
```

I made 2 tries:

When I go to page directly clicking on menu the menu icon is disabled as expected.

But when I get redirected to this page after login, the code does not work.

Can the issue be that the redirect is faster and does not have time to load the page?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

apppresser uses the Angular framework to build a single-page application. Single page applications "fake" page-loads.

Your custom JavaScript is being loaded when the app starts, and is run immediately. When you arrive at your html page *after* the login page the JavaScript already ran on the login page and is not run again on your HTML page.

Whatever code you put in the custom JavaScript will only be run once, when the app starts.

In your case you can fake an onload by putting a hidden image in your custom HTML page:

```
<img src="logo.png" onload="window.disableMenuToggle()" onbeforeunload="window.enableMenuToggle()" style="height:0px;width:0px; position:absolute;" />
```

And declare the functions `disableMenuToggle` and `enableMenuToggle` in your custom JavaScript.

```
window.disableMenuToggle = function () {
  var menuToggle = document.getElementsByClassName("bar-button-menutoggle")
  if (menuToggle.length > 0) {
    menuToggle[0].disabled = true;
  }
}
// repeat for enable...
```

(Img because onload events are only triggered by a select few HTML elements and img is one of them)

**Edit:** your custom HTML also won't be "ready" when the JavaScript runs, so for this part don't use the provided ready function, or use it on the body element.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have updated my question with your suggestion.
Do you think I followed your directions correctly?

Comment: Yep, I think so. You'll still need to wrap all of your custom JS in an anonymous function like in their directions, but I think this will work. Did you give it a try?

Comment: I have tried, but seems not works. I update my code add all into anonymous functions. I'm not an expert programmer so I thing I'm wrong something in code.

Comment: Nope, that's my fault. The image actually has to be real, but it can still be hidden. You can add a tiny png to your site specifically for this, or you could use an existing image that's smaller like a logo or icon.

Comment: ok, done with a real image, but nothing. Does the function I wrote seem correct to you? I have tried to print a simple alert and show, but not disable the menù.

Comment: If the toggles were working before then they should be fine now. I'm sorry, I think the anonymous function is limiting the scope of the toggle functions, does apppresser allow you to remove that?

Comment: I removed the anonymous function and it works. But works only if I click directly on page. After redirect js not works.

Comment: Move the "var menutoggle" inside each toggle function?

Comment: Done. same result :-(. I find it strange that there is no effective way.

Comment: This is a bit much, but try assigning the functions to the window: "window.disableMenuToggle = function(){ ..." and then call them from the window: `onload="window.disableMenuToggle()"`

Comment: ok, nothing, not works. Unfortunately always the same result. I try to ask for support directly to apppresser at this point.